# How to iterate through this object?

Tags: javascript

I want to iterate through this object by creating a `function country(state,foods)`
if the state and foods exists in the object,it should return me the state name and foods array of that state.First i tried iterating only state by passing argument state in the function using `for in` still i didn't get the state name and i don't know what should i do to get foods array.

```
var india = [
        {
            "state": "karnataka",
            "capital": "Bengaluru",
            "foods": ["Mysore masala", "Uthhappa", "Bisi Bele Bhaat"]
        },
        {
            "state": "Maharashtra",
            "capital": "Mumbai",
            "foods": ["vada pav", "puranpoli", "Missal pav"]
        },

        {
            "state": "Tamil nadu",
            "capital": "Chennai",
            "foods": ["Medu vada", "aapam", "idli sambhar"]
        },

        {
            "state": "Rajasthan",
            "capital": "Jaipur",
            "foods": ["Ras malai", "Kadka", "Gujia"]

        }
    ];
```

Comment: use `forEach` or simple `for` loop

Comment: Do you want to find a single food, or exactly match the list of foods, or match if multiple foods you passed in are included in the data?

Comment: @torazaburo i want the foods array,i mean the list of foods

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. You are specifying a function `country(state, foods)`. What I am wondering is, should the function return the state and foods only if the foods you passed to `country` match exactly the foods of that state, or if they are contained in the foods of the state, or do you actually want to pass in a single food and find states whose foods contain that food, along with all of its foods?

Comment: Random thought: why is it called `country` if it's returning a state and foods?

Comment: for instance if i pass country("Maharashtra","foods"),i want to get the states foods array   ["vada pav", "puranpoli", "Missal pav"]

Comment: @SeanT the value of "foods" will have o be an array in order to returning its values correct??

Comment: @SeanT so basically you will need to pass a variable and then an array to the function country is that correct??

Comment: @SeanT or give us as example of what the parameters will be for your function. Thanks

Comment: @HenryDev What i want the function to do is to check the state property first and then (capital or foods property ) if both are true,it should return capital or foods property value

Comment: @SeanT so can I write a function that checks only state and capital? like this: function country(state, capital) ??

Comment: So, one last time. What is the purpose of the `foods` parameter to your `country` function? What does it control? What does it do? What does it mean?

Comment: So what you really want is a function `getStateProp(state, prop)` that will return the value of the specified property associated with the specified state? So saying `getStateProp("Rajasthan", "foods")` would return an array of foods, and saying `getStateProp("Rajasthan", "capital")` would return `"Jaipur"`?

Comment: @SeanT I have posted my solution :). Please take a look at it

Answer (score 2):

This is a poor data structure for your use case, so if you expect to need to search this data often, you might consider having state names as properties on an object for O(1) lookup rather than O(n) approach of iterating this array. That being said, this existing structure can be searched in this case using Array.find().

```
var result = india.find( item => (item.state === this) , searchState);
console.log(result.foods);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i in india)
{
    alert(india[i].state);
    // do something else with india[i]
}
```

Or since `india` is an array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < india.length; ++i)
{
    // same thing
}
```

When searching if a specific number or string exists in an array you can use `Array.indexOf()`, example:

```
if (india[i].foods.indexOf('Kadka') >= 0)
{
    alert(india[i].state + " has food Kadka");
}
```

A function `StateHasFood(state, food)` could be something like that:

```
function StateHasFood(state, food)
{
    for (var i in india)
        if (india[i].state == state)
            return india[i].foods.indexOf(food) >= 0;
    return false;
}
```

Of course you can also return the object relative to the state containing its properties, including it's name and full list of foods like you seem to want:

```
function StateHasFood(state, food)
{
    for (var i in india)
        if (india[i].state == state)
            if (india[i].foods.indexOf(food) >= 0)
                return india[i];
    return false;
}
```

Comment: He requested a `function country(state, foods)`. How would you write that?

Answer (score 0):

Try `forEach()` method to iterate and `Object.keys` to get the key:value pairs. Don't completely understand OP's objective so I'll add `objArrKey()`. This function takes the array and a specific key and return all values associated with said key.

#### SNIPPET

```js
var India = [{
  "state": "karnataka",
  "capital": "Bengaluru",
  "foods": [
    "Mysoremasala",
    "Uthhappa",
    "BisiBeleBhaat"
  ]
}, {
  "state": "Maharashtra",
  "capital": "Mumbai",
  "foods": [
    "vadapav",
    "puranpoli",
    "Missalpav"
  ]
}, {
  "state": "Tamilnadu",
  "capital": "Chennai",
  "foods": [
    "Meduvada",
    "aapam",
    "idlisambhar"
  ]
}, {
  "state": "Rajasthan",
  "capital": "Jaipur",
  "foods": [
    "Rasmalai",
    "Kadka",
    "Gujia"
  ]
}]


India.forEach(function(item) {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log("key:" + key + " value:" + item[key]);
  });
});

function objArrKey(arr, key) {
  return arr.map(function(item) {
    return item[key] || null;
  });
}

console.log(objArrKey(India, ['state']));
console.log(objArrKey(India, ['capital']));
console.log(objArrKey(India, ['foods']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you just told me to write a function to check if state and capital are present, and that is true then return the capital. I have wrote this for you. Hope it helps :)

```js
var india = [
      {
          "state": "karnataka",
          "capital": "Bengaluru",
          "foods": ["Mysore masala", "Uthhappa", "Bisi Bele Bhaat"]
      },
      {
          "state": "Maharashtra",
          "capital": "Mumbai",
          "foods": ["vada pav", "puranpoli", "Missal pav"]
      },

      {
          "state": "Tamil nadu",
          "capital": "Chennai",
          "foods": ["Medu vada", "aapam", "idli sambhar"]
      },

      {
          "state": "Rajasthan",
          "capital": "Jaipur",
          "foods": ["Ras malai", "Kadka", "Gujia"]
      }
  ];

function country(someState , someCapital){
  for (var i in india)
   {
    if(india[i].state === someState && india[i].capital === someCapital){
        return india[i].capital;
    }
  }
}

document.write(country("Tamil nadu", "Chennai"));
```

Comment: Your function doesn't use `someCapital`, so why are you passing it in?

Comment: @torazaburo well he told me to write a function to check if state and capital are part of the object and if they are then return the capital

Comment: @torazaburo I updated my solution to use someCapital.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've added in the comments, it seems what you really want is a function `getPropForState(state, prop)` that will return the value of the specified property associated with the specified state. That is, `getPropForState("Rajasthan", "foods")` would return an array of foods, and `getPropForState("Rajasthan", "capital")` would return `"Jaipur"`.

Assuming that is the case, perhaps something like the following:

```js
// same array as in question, but with line breaks removed
// so that it doesn't clutter up my answer
var india = [{"state":"karnataka","capital":"Bengaluru","foods":["Mysore masala","Uthhappa","Bisi Bele Bhaat"]},{"state":"Maharashtra","capital":"Mumbai","foods":["vada pav","puranpoli","Missal pav"]},{"state":"Tamil nadu","capital":"Chennai","foods":["Medu vada","aapam","idli sambhar"]},{"state":"Rajasthan","capital":"Jaipur","foods":["Ras malai","Kadka","Gujia"]}];

function getPropForState(state, prop) {
  var item = india.find(v => v.state === state);
  if (item)
    return item[prop];
}

console.log(getPropForState("Rajasthan", "foods"));     // returns ["Ras malai","Kadka","Gujia"]
console.log(getPropForState("Rajasthan", "capital"));   // returns "Jaipur"
console.log(getPropForState("Maharashtra", "capital")); // returns "Mumbai"
console.log(getPropForState("Maharashtra", "missing")); // returns undefined
console.log(getPropForState("Queensland", "foods"));    // returns undefined
```

Note that if either the state or the specified other property do not exist then the function will return `undefined`.